# Showing that a certain function is a local diffeomorphism

Tags: analysis

I have to show that $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2: (x,y) \mapsto (e^x(x \cos y - y \sin y),e^x(x \sin y + y \cos y)$ is a local diffeomorphism in ever point not $(-1,0)$.

I have no idea how to invert $f$ on some restricted domain. My guess is that we have to restrict the domain, jut say cos and sin have inverses. However, I have no idea what I could pick as a viable inverse? Since taking logarithms, dividing the result and multiplying or squaring just makes the result more complicated. Could anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*
Calculate [Jacobian matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) for mapping $f: (x,y) \mapsto (e^x(x \cos y - y \sin y),e^x(x \sin y + y \cos y)$ and check its determinant is zero or not.

Comment: Well if the jacobian is not 0 in a point, than the inverse function theorem tells us that it is a local diffeomorphism in that point. But the inverse function theorem is mentioned in the next section, not in this section.